# What are these variables representing when calculating the vertices of a hexagon?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I was looking at a StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26691977/6741482) for computing a grid of hexagons and have since spent a great deal of time attempting to decipher unclear variable names. The answer computes a grid (nevermind how its built, that part I get) starting from $(X_1, Y_1)$ to $(X_2, Y_2)$ for a given radius $R$.

Given a starting point of $(1, 1)$ it computes:

$$sl = (2 * R) * tan(\frac{\pi}{6})$$

$$p = sl * 0.5$$

$$b = sl * cos(30)$$

$$w = b * 2$$

$$h = 2 * sl$$

Now in everything I've read about hexagon geometry, I've not seen these terms. From what I can gather, $b$ ends up equaling $R$, but thats about it. I am not sure what $sl$ is supposed to represent, but $\frac{\pi}{6}$ is 30 degrees so for a pointy top hexagon, that is coming into play, just not sure how.

Can somebody explain how these variables are related to the vertices of a hexagon?

Answer (score 1):

$sl$ seems to be the side length, $p$ is half of it. $b=R$ is the distance from the center to a side-middlepoint. A picture tells more than a $1000$ words.[image]

Note: This is not a math problem. It is just the definition that that particular guy uses in his program. (Unless you wanted us to prove these formulae)

Comment: But shouldnt $sl$ = $R$? The [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagon#Parameters) states that the radius $R$ is equal to the side length $t$. Furthermore, if you compute $sl$ for a radius of $1$, you get $1.1547$ which I believe is incorrect as it should be $1$.

Comment: The radius of the circumcircle is equal to the sidelength. But this circle is an incircle, so the radius is smaller.

Comment: R is the inradius, not the circumradius

Comment: Forgive me, I cannot see the picture (restricted system). So if you labeled the inradius as $R$ I am unaware. However, in my OP, $R$ is the circumradius as provided to their function as the variable `radius`. I'll refrain from responding until I can see your image later.

Comment: No, sorry. The variable 'radius' does not represent the circumradius in that program. It represents the half of the distance beween two opposite sides.
Wikipedia is right about the fact that 'The side length of a regular hexagon is equal to its circumradius'. You can see this by putting six equilateral triangles in the hexagon.

Comment: This definitely is a math question. Perhaps it’s not a math problem, however.